# How to make matlab compile python at every run

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have testPython.py :

```
import numpy as np
def numpyTest():
    print("Testing numpy...")
    x = np.array([1,2,3])
    return x
```

and I have test.m:

```
clear; clc;

value = py.testPython.numpyTest()
```

When I run test.m I get:

Testing numpy...

```
value = 

  Python ndarray with properties:

           T: [1×1 py.numpy.ndarray]
        base: [1×1 py.NoneType]
      ctypes: [1×1 py.numpy.core._internal._ctypes]
        data: [1×24 py.buffer]
       dtype: [1×1 py.numpy.dtype]
       flags: [1×1 py.numpy.flagsobj]
        flat: [1×1 py.numpy.flatiter]
        imag: [1×1 py.numpy.ndarray]
    itemsize: 8
      nbytes: 24
        ndim: 1
        real: [1×1 py.numpy.ndarray]
       shape: [1×1 py.tuple]
        size: 3
     strides: [1×1 py.tuple]

    [1 2 3]
```

But when I go ahead and change the code to be

```
import numpy as np
def numpyTest():
    print("Testing numpy...")
    x = np.array([4,5,6])
    return x
```

It still gives me the same output [1,2,3]. How do I make matlab to compile the python code for every run?

Comment: Try one of the methods described [here](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-modified-python-module.html) depending on your version of Python

Comment: @PawelK Yes, that solved my problem! do you know how to convert numpy array to matlab matrix?